# How exactly does AsQueryable work in Mongodb?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I'm using MongoDb and I write a query with linq like this:

```
var contents = client.GetDatabase("db")
                    .GetCollection<ContentGroup>("contentgroup").AsQueryable()
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == contentGroupId && !x.Deleted.HasValue)?
                       .ContentList?.Where(c =>
                              (c.StartDate == null || c.StartDate <= _clockService.UtcNow) &&
                              (c.EndDate == null || _clockService.UtcNow <= c.EndDate));
```

I have a collection `contentgroup` and it has a field `ContentList` as an array object. I want to get `contentLists` with query.

My questions are:

1. How does `AsQueryable` work exactly?
2. This query run in mongoDb or in .NET client
3. Is there any better way to get array fields in mongodb
4. If this query works on .NET app, so how to run this in mongodb?

Comment: Its likely that it'll be executed in memory on your process, unless you have managed to setup mongodb with efcore. Although I'm not sure if there are any providers available atm.

If you can provide your implementation of `_contentGroupRepository` I might be able to help a bit more?

Comment: I edit code in question.Actually Im worried about performance issue with AsQueryable method if my contentList has much items so Im asking that AsQueryable provides to run query in mongo or in .net application @MattHope